# Retrieving pictures from XML by using a querystring

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I used LINQ to parse images from an XML to a single page. I want to display only one picture when the user clicks on a specific button.The problem is that the listbox is showing all the pictures in the XML at once instead of the one I want it to show. How do I use the  NavigationContext.QueryString to display only the picture that is associated with a particular button? I tried it but it still shows multiple pictures.

Here's a sample of the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <Exercises>
       <Exercise name = "Exercise 1">
         <image>/Images/BeginnerEX/ex1.jpg</image>
         <audio>/Audio/ex1.mp3</audio>
       </Exercise>
       <Exercise name = "Exercise 2">
         <image>/Images/BeginnerEX/ex2.jpg</image>
         <audio>"/Audio/ex2.mp3"</audio>
       </Exercise>
       <Exercise name = "Exercise 3">
         <image>/Images/BeginnerEX/ex3.jpg</image>
         <audio>"/Audio/ex3.mp3"</audio>
       </Exercise>
  </Exercises>
```

Button click event:

```
 private void begButton1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string name = "Exercise 1";
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(string.Format("/BeginnerExercisePage.xaml?Exercise={0}", name), UriKind.Relative));

    }
```

The page I want one picture to be displayed:

```
public partial class BeginnerExercisePage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public BeginnerExercisePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        XDocument beginnerExerciseData = XDocument.Load("BeginnerXML.xml");

        var data = from query in beginnerExerciseData.Descendants("Exercise")
                   select new Exercise
                   {
                       ExImage = (string)query.Element("image"),
                       ExAudio = (string)query.Element("audio")

                   };
        lbBegExPage.ItemsSource = data;

    }

    public class Exercise
    {
        string image;
        string audio;

        public string ExAudio
        {
            get { return audio; }
            set { audio = value; }

        }

        public string ExImage
        {
            get { return image; }
            set { image = value; }

        }

    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        string name = string.Empty;
        if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("name", out name))
        {
            this.lbBegExPage.ItemsSource = name;
        }


    }
}
```

XAML: `Here's the XAML:

```
<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="page name" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <StackPanel  x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <ListBox x:Name="lbBegExPage">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Margin="10">
                         <Image Source="{Binding ExImage}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
             </ListBox.ItemTemplate>    
        </ListBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>

<!--Sample code showing usage of ApplicationBar-->
<!--<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button1.png" Text="Button 1"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button2.png" Text="Button 2"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 1"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 2"/>
        </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>-->
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's your XAML like? I am guessing you have an Image in the ListBox's (lbBegExPage) DataTemplate. You should probably have it outside of the ListBox and set its Source property to {Binding SelectedItem.ExImage, ElementName=lbBegExPage}

Sorry, I misunderstood your intent. Assuming your start page just has 3 hardcoded buttons that pass the name of the exercise in navigation to the second page - you should modify your BeginerExercisePage. Remove all your data code from the constructor and in the OnNavigatedTo override do:

```
    var exercise = (from ex in beginnerExerciseData.Descendants("Exercise")
               where ex.Attribute("name") == name
               select new Exercise
               {
                   ExImage = (string)query.Element("image"),
                   ExAudio = (string)query.Element("audio")
               }).Single();
    im.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(exercise.ExImage, UriKind.Relative));
```

Replace

```
<StackPanel  x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <ListBox x:Name="lbBegExPage">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Margin="10">
                     <Image Source="{Binding ExImage}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
         </ListBox.ItemTemplate>    
    </ListBox>
</StackPanel>
```

With

```
<Image x:Name="im" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0"/>
```

Comment: I tried what you said but the picture dissapeared when I took it of the listbox.

Comment: I did what you suggested and got 3 erros : "does not contain a definition for 'ExImage' and no extension method 'ExImage' accepting a first argument of type" AND "could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" Also "The name 'name' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me resolve this! It still gives me the following errors : The name 'name' does not exist in the current context"  AND   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Uri' to 'System.Windows.Media.ImageSource'

Comment: But you had "name" in your context:     protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        string name = string.Empty;
        if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("name", out name))

Comment: As for image source - you should probably use a BitmapImage instead of just the Uri. Updating the answer.

Comment: Thanks for answerin on Christmas! I really appreciate it! I'm sorry to bother you with one more question. I did the above and it still gave an error: "Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute' and 'string" . I googled the problem, changed a few things and got it to compile with this code http://pastebin.com/pt44E8R4 but now there's just a blank screen.

Comment: I solved it! :) I was passing the wrong query and that's why it didn't show anything. Thank so very much for helping me with this! I wish you all the best!

Comment: Cool, glad to be of assistance

Answer (score 1):

Try this revised code:

```
var data = (from query in beginnerExerciseData.Descendants("Exercise")
                   select new Exercise
                   {
                       ExImage = (string)query.Element("image"),
                       ExAudio = (string)query.Element("audio")

                   }).Take(1);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Now it shows one picture like I wanted. But all other buttons show the same picture. How do I connect the other buttons to other pictures that I parsed? Example: Button1_click shows image1, Button2_click shows image2, Button3_click shows image3 etc. Thank you once again for replying!

Comment: Well, after looking a second time, I think xyzzer is correct, we need to see your XAML.